# Meyer lemon tree is ailing

Tags: diseases, citrus, lemons, scale

[image][image]I've had my Meyer lemon tree for more than 10 years. It's small -- maybe 2 feet tall -- but mighty: This season, it produced 30 (!) lemons that I harvested over the winter.

But by February all its leaves had curled, dried up, and fallen off. It was in a plastic pot on the floor, and we have radiant heat. Not sure if that caused the problem.

I've pruned it back heavily, repotted it, treated it for what looked like cottony cushion scale (using alcohol on a qtip and then spraying with Organocide.) 
I've moved it outside (we live in DC, where daytime temps this week are in the 60s; nights in 50s/40s.)

When I scrape the bark, I see some green. But it sure looks dead. Any thoughts on what might bring it back? Is it still too cold for it to be outside?

It had such an amazing fruiting season; I'd hate to lose it now.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Temps seem fine for it to be outside. The tree would recover if given the proper care. First remove all the dead branches. I see quiet alot in the photos but i also see alot of green which is a sure sign that the tree is alive. Secondly, just to be on the safe side, remove the plant from its container and check for root rot. If all's fine then wait for it to start throwing new leaves and while you do so, make sure that you dont overwater or overfertilize the tree. Infact, dont use any fertilizer at all untill the tree recovers.